# Couchbase Full Text Search Special Character or Accent

Tags: full-text-search, special-characters, couchbase

I would need help setting up a **Couchbase Full Text Search**.

I try to ignore **special characters** such as **accents**, for more flexibility.

I think the solution is in the configuration of "Analyzers" and "Custom Filters".
By creating "**Character filter**" such as this (one for each letter), no effect:

```
Regular Expression: [àáâãäåæ]
Replacement: a
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use `Fuzzy Query`.

As per [Documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/fts/fts-query-types.html):

> A fuzzy query matches terms within a specified edit (or Levenshtein)
>   distance: meaning that terms are considered to match when they are to
>   a specified degree similar, rather than exact. A common prefix of a
>   stated length may be also specified as a requirement for matching.

For your needs I would start with a fuzziness of 1 and try it:

```
{
 "term": "hellå",
 "field": "test.field",
 "fuzziness": 1  
}
```

If you're using the SDK you can find an usage example [here](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/java/full-text-searching-with-sdk.html).

For example:

```
TermQuery query = SearchQuery.term("hellå").field("test.field").fuzziness(1);
```

Comment: I can't and don't want to use another Query Type, the search result is too wide.